# XP cant access Active Directory (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational at )

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp

I have the problem that I cannot access Active Directory from a Windows XP SP3 machine. The server is a Windows Server 2008 R2. I could access AD from my Windows 7 and other machines, but XP won't work.

I get the Exception...

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne) at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()

please help me.

regards

denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to point the DNS of TCP/IP v4 to the AD?

Comment: No i didnt. Iam no Administrator, could you provide some informations how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved the same and different, the domain used for Environment.UserDomainName, but this only brings the name, such as "google.com" Environment.UserDomainName = "google" in windows 7 no problem, but not xp can read well, add the reference manually touch

domain = Environment.UserDomainName.ToUpper (). Contains (". COM")? Environment.UserDomainName: Environment.UserDomainName +. "Com"

note: Validate that if it comes with. com do not add